# Android BLE App can ONLY subscribe characteristic notification for 1 BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to Android. I'm trying to subscribe characteristic notifications from 2 BLE devices. Now, my App can only receive the BLE data from the 1st device.
I understand that BLE is serial communication, so I must wait until the onDescriptorWrite() callback is called before I enable the notification for the 2nd device. We can ONLY have 1 GATT operation each time.
**My questions are:**

1. How to modify the **onDescriptorWrite()**? **Thread.sleep() delay method** doesn't help.
2. Some people mentioned to use **queue** to add/remove something?

   ```
    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled,int device) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null || mBluetoothGatt1 == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    if(device == 0) {
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"Device #0 is done for notification!");
    }
    else if(device == 1){
        mBluetoothGatt1.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic,enabled);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"Device #1 is done for notification!");
    }
   ```

   }

   ```
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.e(TAG, "Connected to GATT server #0.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.e(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery #0:" + mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.e(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server #0.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic,0);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(700);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"onCHAR READ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic,0);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(700);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"onCharacteristicChanged #0 = ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, Done! ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);

        // Do something here ????????????

        // Thread.sleep() delay method doesn't help
        try {
            Thread.sleep(700);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"onDescriptorWrite #0, Done! ");
    }
   ```

   };

Comment: Does `onDescriptorWrite` get called after you enabled the notifications for the first characteristic?

Comment: Hi @M. Kotzjan , Thanks for your support. Yes, onDescriptorWrite() is called for the 1st characteristic. That's why I can receive 1 BLE device data.

Comment: Please never use delays/sleep like tihs in BLE code. It will never help you in a correct way. Anyway, the rule of only having one pending operation in progress is per BluetoothGatt object, so you can safely have two pending operations in parallel if they are to one device each.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mBluetoothGatt1.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic,enabled);
 BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
 descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
 mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

I think that should be:

```
 mBluetoothGatt1.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic,enabled);
 BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
 descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
 mBluetoothGatt1.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Comment: Hi @Emil, this is a typo, thanks for pointing it out. If I understand your comment correctly, u mean that I need to have 2 BluetoothGatt objects for 2 BLE peripheral devices? Yes, I did the same way. I created `private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt; private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt1;` Then, I have `mGattCallback and mGattCallback1`. I have 2 same callback functions, just change mBluetoothGatt to mBluetoothGatt1. But still no luck. I have updated the above code to include 2 GattCallback() functions. Someone suggested using the Queue/ArrayList method. Do you know how to achieve it, please?

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on your topic post, you do not need to queue up operations in one single queue for multiple BluetoothGatt objects. You probably have a bug in some part of your code which you have not included in your post.